# VSCode failed to attach to process

Tags: visual-studio-code, gdb, remote-debugging

I am using VSCode on Windows to debug a process on remote Linux host. I have added launch configuration that look like this:

```
        {
            "type": "gdb",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to PID",
            "target": "3441",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
        },
```

But when I am trying to launch debugged I get this output in Debug console:

```
Attaching to process 3441
[New LWP 3442]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libthread_db.so.1".
__libc_do_syscall () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/libc-do-syscall.S:47
47  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/libc-do-syscall.S: No such file or directory.
Not implemented stop reason (assuming exception): undefined
```

The last line looks suspicious as if the debugger was not able to stop the process for some reason. At the same time a message box with the following text is displayed:

`Failed to attach: Cannot change this setting while the inferior is running. (from gdb-set target-async on)`

I tried running gdb on the machine through ssh and attach to the process and it works ok.

So the question is: how do I get this running? I also tried enabling logging by adding this to `launch.json`:

```
"logging": {
    "engineLogging": false
}
```

But vscode editor claims `Property logging is not allowed` and it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Any ideas?